# WeatherRoom service down need a alternative for a website

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

OKay I don't use actionscript and trying to help my friend edit a flash website which the layout changes based on a xml feed from weatherroom.com which is now defunk, the dev of this site has also left my friend (his client).  This is the current code bellow, is there anyway I can simply swap for another service and not have to hire a person to do the actionscript all overagain

```
updateWeatherData() {
//record old settings
var oldCondition = _root.currentCondition;
var oldWeather = _root.currentWeather;
var oldTimeset = _root.currentTimeset;
//get new settings
var newTimeObj = _root.getCurNYTime();
_root.currentTimeset = newTimeObj.timeSet /*'night'*/;
var myURL:String = 'http://www.weatherroom.com/xml/zip/12545';
var myXMLweatherData:XML = new XML();
myXMLweatherData.load(myURL);
myXMLweatherData.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {
        _root.XMLWeatherFeed = this;
        //extract current condition (string)
        _root.currentCondition = _root.getCurrentCondition(_root.XMLWeatherFeed);
        //get current weather number
        _root.currentWeather = _root.getCurrentWeather(_root.currentCondition) /*2*/;
        //display
        _root.displayAllWeatherInfo(_root.XMLWeatherFeed);
        if (_root.initWeatherDone == true) {
            //compare if weather has changed
            if (oldCondition != _root.currentCondition or oldWeather != _root.currentWeather or oldTimeset != _root.currentTimeset) {
                if (_root.currentCondition != undefined and _root.currentWeather != undefined and _root.currentTimeset != undefined) {
                    console.text += ('-> ' + oldCondition + ' :: ' + _root.currentCondition + '\n');
                    console.text += ('-> ' + oldWeather + ' :: ' + _root.currentWeather + '\n');
                    console.text += ('-> ' + oldTimeset + ' :: ' + _root.currentTimeset + '\n');
                    //if it has, launch weather update
                    _root.updateWeatherBackground();
                } else {
                    console.text += ('--! weather server returned uncomplete data !--');
                    //restore data
                    _root.currentCondition = oldCondition;
                    _root.currentWeather = oldWeather;
                    _root.currentTimeset = oldTimeset;
                }
            } else {
                console.text += ('--! no necessary update !--');
            }
        } else {
            //tell app init has been done
            _root.initWeatherDone = true;
        }
    } else {
        //-- server is down
        //-- return partly cloudy no rain
        trace('*** SERVER IS DOWN ***');
        _root.currentWeather = 3;
        _root.initWeatherDone = true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to need to hire someone else. The reason I say that is that any other service you use is going to have to have EXACTLY the same XML layout for your code to just "plug into it." For example, `_root.getCurrentCondition()` is probably a method that looks for a specific node inside the XML and returns a value in a specific format. Unless the attributes and text are exactly the same (name, pattern, etc.), it's just not going to work.

Good luck.